# php- get postback from a hyperlink

Tags: php, html, post, hyperlink, get

I have a HTML form in which I'm having the following hyperlink:

```
<a href="" id="WhatsNew">What's New</a></li>
```

I want to get a postback from this hyperlink, in order to execute the following PHP code:

```
if($_POST['WhatsNew'] == "Y")
{             
  echo "HELLO USER";
}
```

How can I do so?

Comment: don't understand the problem explain in brief??

Comment: @Vicky As we get a postback from submit button in PHP($_POST['button_name'], I want to get a postback from a hyperlink, in order to execute some PHP code...

Comment: You can't use POST unless you use submit button..but You can do it by using query strings

Comment: are you wanting to execute the script to return a value or do you need to page to reload?  If you are just reloading the page but showing extra info if `whatsnew` is present then I would use the get variable as shown, in the answers below, otherwise you can bind an onclick event to the link and make an ajax post (using javascript)

Comment: @RahulMishra, you can post without a submit button, you just need a a bit of js

Comment: @Pete Actually my PHP code will be opening an HTML popup on hyperlink click. For that purpose I needed a postback from hyperlink...

Comment: Ah, in that case the `get` is probably the better option

Comment: @Pete I know that we can post without PHP using jq/jq/ajax .... here there is no need of that..thats why i doesn't mentioned

Comment: @RahulMishra, just saying your above comment is wrong - you categorically say you can't post without a submit button - that's not true you can do, it's just there is no need to here

Comment: @Pete yes we can do ... my mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html where you can send id by using `?` like this

```
<a href="mypage?whatsnew=1" id="WhatsNew">What's New</a>
```

and if you are sending some value through url you have to use $_GET instead of $_POST like below

```
$whatsnew=$_GET['whatsnew'];

    if(!empty($whatsnew) && $whatsnew == 1)
    {             
      echo "HELLO USER";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [Query Strings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HofYfGbmg88)

```
<a href="mypage?whatsnew=1" id="WhatsNew">What's New</a>
```

Your PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['whatsnew']) && $_GET['whatsnew'] == 1)
{             
  echo "HELLO USER";
}
```